# AWS cross region replication to multiple regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to set up cross region replication so that my original file will be replicated to two different regions. Right now, I can only get it to replicate to one other region.

For example, my files are on US Standard. When a file is uploaded it is replicated from US Standard to US West 2. I would also like for that file to be replicated to US West 1.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears the Cross-Region Replication in Amazon S3 **cannot be chained**. Therefore, it cannot be used to replicate from Bucket A to Bucket B to Bucket C.

An alternative would be to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to synchronise between buckets, eg:

```
aws s3 sync s3://bucket1 s3://bucket2
aws s3 sync s3://bucket1 s3://bucket3
```

The `sync` command only copies new and changed files. Data is transferred directly between the Amazon S3 buckets, even if they are in different regions -- no data is downloaded/uploaded to your own computer.

So, put these commands in a `cron` job or a Scheduled Task to run once an hour and the buckets will nicely replicate!

See: [AWS CLI S3 sync command documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)