# S3 path objects replication to 2 different AWS accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Can I replicate s3 objects in one path to 2 different accounts with 2 different replication rules?

I've tried with one-one account replication but I want the same data in another AWS account too. So will it be possible to add 2 replication rules on same bucket path in source bucket and get the replicates into 2 different AWS accounts?

Comment: Did you try it? What was the result?

Comment: I've tried setting up another rule to point to a different bucket, it doesn't seem to work that way. One prefix can only be replicated to one bucket i guess.

Comment: That seems to match the findings in: [AWS cross region replication to multiple regions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31800445/174777)